# WPF create object using IValueConverter with binding object's properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

my objects which I use to binding in XAML can have only string properties. But in binding I need other type. I thought that I use Converter function from IValueConverter, where I'll create object from string properties and return this. One property which is a string will be empty, and in binding I'll return other object from Converter method. I tried this but in Convert method my main object from ObservableCollection is null. This's a piece of my XAML

```
<Maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent" Tapped="ItemStckPanel">
                        <Image Source="/Assets/pushpin.gif" Height="30" Width="30" 
                               Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location, 
                            Converter={StaticResource StringToGeopoint}}" 
                                Maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="0.5,0.5"/>
                        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
                            <TextBlock FontSize="20" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </Maps:MapItemsControl>
```

And this's my Convert method:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        Event _event = (Event) parameter;

        BasicGeoposition position = new BasicGeoposition();
        position.Latitude = _event.Latitude;
        position.Longitude = _event.Longitude;

        return new Geopoint(position);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to pass the my actual parent object in Converter method. Solution is change

```
Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location, 
                        Converter={StaticResource StringToGeopoint}}"
```

to

```
Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Converter={StaticResource StringToGeopoint}}"
```

It works :)

Answer (score 0):

The bound object is fed into the "value" parameter of the Convert()-Method.

You're accessing the parameter which corresponds to

```
<... ConverterParameter= .../>
```

which isn't set in your xaml.

You would actually have to write your Convert()-Method like this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    Event _event = (Event) value;

    BasicGeoposition position = new BasicGeoposition();
    position.Latitude = _event.Latitude;
    position.Longitude = _event.Longitude;

    return new Geopoint(position);

}
```

/UPDATE:

The ItemsSource={Binding} on your Maps:MapItemControl binds to the DataContext of the parent object. This should be your ObservableCollection.

Within the ItemTemplate your Image has a "Location"-Property that is bound to the "Location"-property of each item within your ObservableCollection. You could also write:

```
{Binding Path=Location, Converter={StaticResource StringToGeopoint}}
```

Now before that binding is fully evaluated, the Object that is stored in the Location-property is passed to the converter and the result is then handed to the "Location"-Property on the Image.

If you are getting null objects to be passed to the "value"-parameter, that means that the original Binding hands null values to the Converter either because the Property on the source object is null or because the property doesn't exist.

Comment: What should I add in ConverteParameter? I changed to parameter in Converter method but it's stil not working. Maybe I will explain one more time. In Converter method I want to have the access to my object which contains Location property.

Comment: The ConverterParameter is a static Attribute that cannot change via binding. But your original Binding might be incorrect, I'll edit the original post to explain.

Comment: The problem is I need my object which is Event type from ObservableCollection in DataContext in Converter method. This object has string Longitude and Latitude. In Location I need Geopoint from this strings which I'll return to Binding Path=Location. Location in my Event type is "ghost property".